# How to HTTPCALL in HPCCECL having authorization , JSON output GET Method as it gives empty string

Tags: authentication, get, hpcc

Can you please suggest how to optimize below code to fetch roxie queries related values properly
IMPORT Std;

WUListQueriesResponse :- Is same as we get in layout .

QueryList :=  HTTPCALL('https://CCSssSDSDSGVVXX/WsWorkunits/WUListQueries?ver_=1.95&amp ',
'GET',
'application/json',
WUListQueriesResponse,
XPATH('/WUListQueriesResponse'),
HTTPHEADER('Authorization','BASIC XXXXXXXX')
);
QueryList;

Output the above BWR.
getting below error .
Error:    Error - syntax error "Expecting "{ or ["" [file offset 1]
<?*ERROR*xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><WUListQueriesResponse><NumberOfQueries>79https://XXCVVdshdnet:18010/WsWorkunits/WUListQueries?ver_=1.95&amp  (in HTTP dataset 2) (0, 0), 2,